# SSL Error - wrong version number (HTTPS to HTTP)

Tags: javascript, flask, https, openssl, stunnel

I receive an error when i try to "redirect" and https request to http by a stunnel server.

construction:

***flask server:*** serve https which includes an button with a https request to another server (stunnel4).

***stunnel:*** receives the request and redirect it to a local (http) server.

*the stunnel server failes by following error:*

```
Mär 27 19:27:20 raspberrypi stunnel[1400]: LOG5[1744]: Service [https] accepted connection from <external_IP>:51874
Mär 27 19:27:20 raspberrypi stunnel[1400]: LOG5[1744]: s_connect: connected <local_IP>:7777
Mär 27 19:27:20 raspberrypi stunnel[1400]: LOG5[1744]: Service [https] connected remote server from <local_IP>:45444
Mär 27 19:27:20 raspberrypi stunnel[1400]: LOG3[1744]: SSL_connect: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

is it possible that this error caused by my manually (not officially certificatied) created SSL certificates?

flask server --> uses an manual created cert and key file.
stunnel4 uses --> uses an manual created cert and key file (but different to flasks SSL files)

if you know any other methods to "redirect" the https to http, please comment.

Comment: That error means that the server is rejecting the version of SSL/TLS that the client is using. i.e. the server is setup to only accept TLS v1.2 or v1.3 and the client is trying to connect using TLS v1.1 then you will get the "wrong version number".

Comment: i receive the error even when i set the stunnel.conf "ssl_version = all"

Comment: I'm only telling you what the error means, I can't tell you how to fix it as I don't know stunnel or flask server.   It does seem like it's a stunnel configuration issue.  Maybe see if there is a outbound ssl version you can set.  I would try to set it to tls1.2.