# error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number for https on Istio ingressgateway

Tags: ssl, istio, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to set up SSL on port 443 on an ingressgateway. I can consistently reproduce with a very basic setup. I know it is something I am probably doing wrong but haven't been able to figure it out.

My k8s cluster is running on EKS. `k version 1.19`

I created a certificate with AWS Certificate Manager for domain `api.foo.com` and additional names `*.api.foo.com`
The certificate was created successfully and has ARN `arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:<some-numbers>:certificate/<id>`

Then I did a vanilla install of istio:
`istioctl install --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout`

With version:

```
client version: 1.7.0
control plane version: 1.7.0
```

This is my gateway definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: foo-gateway
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:<some-numbers>:certificate/<id>"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "elb"
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https-443
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
```

Note that port 443 has protocol HTTP, I don't believe that is the problem (since I want to use SSL termination). Also even if I change it to HTTPS, then I get this:

```
Resource: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3, Resource=gateways", GroupVersionKind: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3, Kind=Gateway"
Name: "foo-gateway", Namespace: "default"
for: "foo-gateway.yaml": admission webhook "validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: server must have TLS settings for HTTPS/TLS protocols
```

But then what would be the tls settings? I need the certificate key to be picked up through the annotation (from AWS CM) not placed in `/etc`. As an aside, is there a way to do this without ssl termination?

My VirtualService definition is this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: foo-api
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - foo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /users
    route:
    - destination:
        host: https-user-manager
        port:
          number: 7070
```

I then `k apply -f` a super simple REST service called `https-user-manager` on port 7070. I then find the host name for the load balancer from a `k get svc -n istio-system` which yields:

```
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   <cluster-ip>    blahblahblah.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com   15021:30048/TCP,80:30210/TCP,443:31349/TCP,15443:32587/TCP   32m
```

I can successfully use http like:
`curl http://blahblahblah.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/users` and get a valid response

But then if I do this:
`curl -vi https://blahblahblah.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/users` I get the following:

```
*   Trying <ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.foo.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

What am I doing wrong? I have seen these https://medium.com/faun/managing-tls-keys-and-certs-in-istio-using-amazons-acm-8ff9a0b99033, [Istio-ingressgateway with https - Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130724/istio-ingressgateway-with-https-connection-refused), [Setting up istio ingressgateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379353/setting-up-istio-ingressgateway), [SSL Error - wrong version number (HTTPS to HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899222/ssl-error-wrong-version-number-https-to-http), [Updating Istio-IngressGateway TLS Cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621461/updating-istio-ingressgateway-tls-cert), https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3556, https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14264, https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/, https://preliminary.istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/, among many others that I don't even remember anymore. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: What's is your istio ingress gateway tls mode configuration? Could you try with tls mode PASSTHROUGH as mentioned [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-571673253)? Have you tried to change the istio-ingress gateway instead of new created one? There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63578352).

Answer (score 0):

```
low level nginx  
ssl on;  
high level nginx  
listen 443 ssl;
```

this works for me

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?